# How to list tables in RethinkDb using C++

Tags: c++, driver, rethinkdb

When I do something in `Python` or in `JavaScript` I always have a lot of opportunities, both, to read documentation of a particular library and to try tons of teeny-weeny examples.

Unfortunatelly, in `C++` it is not so popular (for what reason?) to provide at least a little ammount of working examples in documentation. Two good examples are C++ clients for [MongoDb](http://api.mongodb.org/cxx/current/annotated.html) and [RethinkDb](https://github.com/AtnNn/librethinkdbxx/).

My question here concerns `RethinkDB`. In `Python` I know [how](http://rethinkdb.com/api/python/table_list/) to list all table names, not because there is documentation and I'm supposed to dive into the driver code, but just because there is a tiny handy example of doing this:

```
r.db('test').table_list().run(conn)
```

And I'm done. In `C++` I do not know how to do this - how to list all table names. I do not know even if there is such a method. I wish someone could provide little instructions and share their knowledge.

**EDIT**

It seems, like I found an appropriate method `table_list`, but unfortunatelly I do not know how to use it. Besides, it seems that I try to connect to the database in a wrong manner - by this I mean that I connect to the server, but not to a particular database (and again I do not know how to implement this). So, this is what I have now:

```
std::unique_ptr<R::Connection> conn = R::connect("localhost",28105);
//^^^ I want to connect to a particular database "mydb" - how to do that?
R::Cursor cursor = R::table_list().run(*conn);
for(R::Datum& item : cursor){
    do_something(R::write_datum(item).c_str());
    //           ^^^ is that right???
}
```

If I do it, like I showed - without specifying the database name, then I get nothing. If, however, I try to connect like this:

```
R::connect("localhost",28105,"mydb");
```

then inside `for` I get an infinite loop. So, I need some help. Thanks!

**EDIT**

Phew, I found a solution. And I must confess, that it is rather intuitive. I will post it below.

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution:

```
std::unique_ptr<R::Connection> conn = R::connect("localhost",28105);
R::Cursor cursor = R::db("mydb").table_list().run(*conn);
for(R::Datum& item : cursor){
  do_something(R::write_datum(item).c_str());
}
```

and it works great. I want to thank `AtnNn` - the sole developper of this great driver.

Comment: The only thing that hurts a little bit - is a benchmark in my `Ubuntu` machine. `Python` client `rethinkdb` turns out to be exactly one hundred times faster than `boost::python` module built on top of this `C++` driver.